# How to validate a number in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a TextBox that the user need to fill with data a number between 0-90
with 3 decimal places (ex. 0.123 , 1.456 , 1.3 , 45)

i need to validate it.

i can use some validation controls.

1. RangeValidator with type double, min 0 , max 90
2. RegularExpressionValidator

what is better?

Comment: Why couldn't you just use a RangeValidator with the range being `.001` to `90`?

Comment: A regex is tricky as it understands just characters, not values. You probably want to accept "90", but not "90.321".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it with [progressive enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement) in mind.

First make a non-javascript version where the textbox is validated server-side.

Second make a nice javascript validation using a RangeValidator.

Keep the RegEx validator's for phone numbers (1800 Plumbing) , emails, fax's & etc.

Answer (score 0):

Is this 3 decimal places exactly or it can vary? If it’s 3 exactly I’d go with regex validator because I’m not sure range validator can validate for exact number of decimal places.

Also you need to make sure these are validated on the server side as well.

Comment: The validators work both client-side and server-side. Except for CustomValidator, where you have to write both sides yourself.